# image display in PHP when the image is in a remote directory

Tags: php

I am learning PHP by myself for doing my final year project, but I cant figure it out how to display images on my website if the image is in my ftp.  I know how to do in html using local host, but I dont know how to do it on my specific remote host.

I am currently using the code:

```
echo '<img src="'.public_html/logo.gif.'" style=width:"' . 300 . 'px;height:' . 280 . 'px;">';
```

If I right click on the image on my directory and select copy url it gives me:

```
ftp://smart206@smartdatabasesystem.com/public_html/logo.gif
```

but if I put all of that it still doesnt work. I am using lunar pages host recommended by w3schools.

If someone has any idea of how to fix my problem, please reply. I read some tutorials, my image display incorrectly. The website I started to develop is smartdatabasesystem.com

Thank you :-)

Comment: I am using:    Sorry, it did not displayed above ->  echo '<img src="'.public_html/logo.gif.'" style=width:"' . 300 . 'px;height:' . 280 . 'px;">';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your FTP host and HTTP host are the same machine (both "local"), but the FTP root directory (and protocol - `ftp://`, obviously) are different. Your http root directory is INSIDE  your `public_html` directory, so your logo is available at:

http://smartdatabasesystem.com/logo.gif

Basically, for your server set up (this will be different on different servers), you can presume that any time you have an FTP location of `ftp://smart206@smartdatabasesystem.com/public_html/[SOMETHING]`, the resource will be available at `http://smartdatabasesystem.com/[SOMETHING]`. If the file is below the `/public_html/` directory, then the resource will not be available to the outside world through HTTP.

Also, Lunar pages is a fine host, but you might catch some flack for taking any suggestions from w3chools... they're not exactly well respected by more senior developers :)

Comment: That works perfectly, but when it comes to my actual code to display on my website, it gives me an error and does not display the image.  :-(  even with the code: echo '<img src="'.http://smartdatabasesystem.com/logo.gif.'" style=width:"' . 300 . 'px;height:' . 280 . 'px;">';

Comment: Your code is not formatted correctly. The src property must either be absolute, relative, relative to root, or protocol-relative: `src='http://smartdatabasesystem.com/logo.gif'` OR `src='../logo.gif'` (assuming that your file is one directory above the logo) OR `src='/logo.gif'` OR `src='//smartdatabasesystem.com/logo.gif'`

Comment: Also, your php string concatenation is messed up... strings must be wrapped in quotes, and there is no reason for you to be concatenatinating in any case. Your PHP should be: `<? echo '<img src="http://smartdatabasesystem.com/logo.gif"; style="width:300px;height:280px;">';`